# why .Select or .ToList() is giving Nested JSON while .Count is comming in parent JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

all three(`Attendance,InTime,OutTime`  ) are coming from the referenced Table

```
Attendence = CheckAttendance.Where(y => y.EmployeeId == x.EmployeeId).Count(),
InTime = CheckAttendance.Where(y => y.EmployeeId == x.EmployeeId).Select(y=>y.StartTime).ToList(),
OutTime = CheckAttendance.Where(y => y.EmployeeId == x.EmployeeId).Select(y=>y.EndTime),
```

C# api code

```
 var TentId = objdb.Adminsitrators.Where(x => x.AdminId == AdminId).Select(x => x.TenantID).SingleOrDefault();
 var emp = objdb.Employees.Where(x=>x.TenantID== TentId).ToList(); 
         if (emp.Count > 0)
           {
             var CheckAttendance = objdb.EmpAttendances.Where(x => x.Status == "Present" & x.TenantID==TentId & x.StartTime.Year == StartTime.Year & x.StartTime.Month == StartTime.Month & x.StartTime.Day == StartTime.Day).ToList();
             var list = emp.Select(x => new
               {
                  EmpID = x.EmployeeId,
                  EmpName = x.Name,
                  EmpImage = "Areas/Admin/Image/" + x.Image,
                  Configured = fileResult(x.EmployeeId),
                  Attendence = CheckAttendance.Where(y => y.EmployeeId == x.EmployeeId).Count(),
                  InTime = CheckAttendance.Where(y => y.EmployeeId == x.EmployeeId).Select(y=>y.StartTime).ToList(),
                  OutTime = CheckAttendance.Where(y => y.EmployeeId == x.EmployeeId).Select(y=>y.EndTime),
                    }).ToList();

                    Value["result"] = "TRUE";
                    Value["Data"] = list;
                }
```

JSON result

```
 "result": "TRUE",
    "Data": [
        {
            "EmpID": 14,
            "EmpName": "Arun Kumar",
            "EmpImage": "Areas/Admin/Image/EmployeeImg_55991775.JPG",
            "Configured": 0,
            "Attendence": 1,                 //Count Data
            "InTime": [
                "2019-05-21T16:13:18.873"    //Tolist
            ],
            "OutTime": [
                "2019-05-21T16:12:51.967"    //Select
            ]
        },
```

Comment: `Attendence` is an integer, not a list like `InTime` and `OutTime`. Therefore, when converted to JSON, there is only the value not a list of values (same as in c#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you could have multiple InTime or OutTime values, so they are serialized as a JSON array, but when you .Count() a collection you turn it into a scalar value.  Use .Max(), .First() or .OrderBy(...).Take(1), if you want to select a single value from a collection.  Or .Single() if you know the collection always contains a single item.

Comment: yes that's the problem when using Single/max()/First() getting Sequence contains no elements because the intime and outtime may be null and it's just a single column value

Comment: @ArunPratap if you need to account for nulls, then use `SingleOrDefault`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the relationshipt, Select and ToList may cause multiple results. 
if you want the Max time or the last inserted value from Intime and OutTime you should query it. Also, you can use .FirstOrDefault() instead.